# Can I use PWM signal to control devices that requires a system clock - OV7670

Tags: arduino, stm32, pwm, oscillator, camera

I want to use the simple camera ov7670 and that camera requires a system clock, called **XCLK**.

[image]

The clock requries 24 MHz input from a source that are at 50% duty call and a period of 24 nanoseconds.
[image]

Does this mean that I should use a PWM signal from a micro controller, or should I use an external crystal oscillator?

http://web.mit.edu/6.111/www/f2016/tools/OV7670_2006.pdf

Comment: if you have a microcontroller that can output a 24 MHz clock signal, then go for it

Comment: @jsotola Yes. I have an STM32 where the PWM's are very very high. Servral MHz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an external Crystal Osc. (XO) with the duty cycle specifications given. That will satisfy the pulse width variations given for the range of frequencies also given.

Comment: So using a PWM output, is a bad idea? Even if the input requries a CMOS clock signal e.g square wave.

Comment: Yes , it's a bad idea. PWM is not used at these frequencies.  and the fastest clocks for CMOS need to be symmetrical

Comment: Ok. Thank you! Best answer! :)

Answer (score 3):

many STM32 microcontrollers have a MCO output. (MCO standing for "Master Clock Out"). it's a general purpose clock output which is derived from a flexible selection of various clock sources and a clock prescaler.
here's an image from the STM32F030 datasheet:

[image: STM32 MCO output]

The XCLK on 7670 could be from 10MHz to 48MHz. it's not 24MHz necessarily.

Comment: Sorry! I using a STM32F407